# How can you read php input stream with Wordpress filesystem methods?

Tags: wordpress, paypal-ipn

I have to rewrite a piece of code on a WordPress theme that handles Paypal payments. The theme is to be published on themeforest.net, so it needs to be checked with Theme Check plugin .

On the file that handle the IPN from Paypal i have this code

```
$raw_post_data  = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

and i receive this error

```
"file_get_contents was found in the file xxx File operations should use the WP_Filesystem methods instead of direct PHP filesystem calls."
```

My question is : 
How can i read the input stream with Wordpress methods ?  I tried wp_remote_get('php://input') but obviously it does not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution. It seems to work fine and pass the theme check plugin.

```
global $wp_filesystem;
if (empty($wp_filesystem)) {
            require_once (ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php');
            WP_Filesystem();
        }

//$raw_post_data  = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_data =  $wp_filesystem->get_contents('php://input');
```